# Engine light turn off sometimes and sometimes stays on

Tags: engine, ignition, cel

When I turn on the ignition of car, it shows the light of oil, battery and engine. Sometimes it tun off and sometimes stay on. When it turn off the car starts easily. when engine light stays on, car is just cranking. any idea what to check?
I went to the mechanic and he couldn't diagnose the problem as car was starting normally. I have recently changed the alternator, spark plugs, head gaskit (as it was leaking and oil went to spark plugs as the car was keep cranking and was getting start to diagnose the mechanic opens the spark it was full of oil so he changed the head gaskit as it was leaking.)
My car is Mitsubishi Lancer 1999 model.

Comment: Did your mechanic read the stored fault codes in the ECU?  Your car is new enough to have an OBD port so the first step would be to get the fault code log read and see what it points to.

Comment: He tested using machine not sure it was ECU or what  but using that he said i didnt found any thing fault. My car has cell in it. last week i check the cell power was at 80%. is it because of the battery of key? one of my friend was suggesting it might be fuel pump which get on when the ignition turn or might be not turning out thats why the light appears.

Answer (score 0):

When the ignition key is turned, the car will start checking all the systems for it's functioning. 
Your car is equipped with sensors that does the check, it always advisable to wait for 5-10 seconds before you crank up the engine. 
The lights will go off once the checks are complete. 
Once you start your car,most of the lights go off, just in case if the lights didn't off, start the troubleshooting,

I would suggest you to check your starter system,airflow sensor, oxygen sensor. They could be culprit

Comment: The thing which i couldn't understand is when i turn on the ignition as you said the system test all the functions and after 3-5 sec the engine light turned off and key then further push to crank and it starts. After it starts there is no light on the dash. But sometimes, when the ignition is ON the engine light turn off and then on again and when try to start it keeps cranking. so sometimes it work fine and sometimes keep cranking

Comment: Intermittency suggests a sometimes good/sometimes bad electrical conneciion...somewhere,